Nullable open generic arguments in C# class hierarchy
Consider this generic class hierarchy of EF Core entities:
public abstract class Parent<TUserKey>
  where TUserKey : IEquatable<TUserKey>  // same signature as IdentityUser<TKey>
{
  protected Parent() { }                 // non-public ctor for use by EF

  protected Parent(TUserKey? userId) { UserId = userId; }

  public long Id { get; }
  public TUserKey? UserId { get; }      // nullable because optional relationship
  // other properties...
}


public sealed class Child : Parent<long>
{
  private Child() : base() { }          // non-public ctor for use by EF

  public Child(long? userId) : base(userId) { }       // <----- PROBLEM HERE
  // other properties...
}

That won't compile:

cannot convert from 'long?' to 'long'

Ideas:

I could declare the parent class with where TUserKey : struct, IEquatable<TUserKey>. However that isn't suitable because some subclasses use string as the type.
I could change the subclass' ctor to public Child(long userId) : base(userId) { }. However many call sites pass a long?, so I'd need to use userId! everywhere.

I suspect I'm stuck with (2), but maybe I've overlooked something. Is there a better way, without a major rewrite?
(BTW: the purpose of TUserKey : IEquatable<TUserKey> is to match the signature of IdentityUser<TKey>.)

The reason is that in the base class the nullability part is just an attribute, the actual type of the argument is just TUserKey, with an attribute saying it is nullable. This is a limitation of the .NET system in which a class that has an open generic argument that is nullable, with no constraint saying it is either a value type or a reference type, this is the best it can do.

You can see it here: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoBBmABM3AYVwG9NcL88EAWXAWQAoBKU8ygX0y40x1wjAAzgBcAThADGI/ElwAFCGICmMEQB4AKgFUhysQGllATwB87AO4ALfctw69hk7hC4AkgFEAjgFcIIwQAbZS1dfSMzCgB6KNwhCDA7ISgAcxh/HxUBIXcAE1URKBFjMLEtCPMMMgwKAAcxAHsRZWllXIUlApZSXA5KfoGBmNwYBpgAWn5pBrFcADMZ3B89XGBjXA8AMUx2eqaW5vbFFTVGB3CTAH4lxzdc1hJcUrvcAF4b/TuAbl6dmqpcIExik8j0UsoRD8eBR+OcnMZrs92o9wZDeoNhjAfIFAkE7MAWhBlnYGrVCmMIIFcCpceSYEIrFBauxhk0bLM9rV9IVlEIAHQC7hAA==

@LasseV.Karlsen Thanks. I suspected it's a design-time annotation only, but was (foolishly) hoping there is some way around it. I guess I'm stuck with foo! everywhere, which is OK.

So the issue is already present in the base class, you say that the UserId property is nullable, but it really isn't.

You could create two distinct base classes, one for value types and one for reference types. This would compile to the correct code, but depending on other factors might not be what you want.

Thanks that is actually a decent workaround in my particular case! Didn't think of it.

If you have common bits so that some places you want to treat an entity as a Parent<T>, you can use an interface to give common access to those bits, just be warned that trying to expose the nullable open generic UserId through that interface will just resurface the same problem in the interface as well.

Additionally, you can put the common bits in yet another base class, which would then be the parent for both the value type intermediary, and the reference type intermediary. The actual UserId would then live in the intermediaries, and all the common code in the "ultimate" base class.

However, is "UserId" as a concept this fluent in your system? Isn't it some kind of static identifier that will always be a string, or a number or a guid, or something? Does it really vary between entity types how you reference a user?

Assuming I understand you correctly, it's not static - it's the user's primary key. The generic complexity is because this code is in a separate helper assembly used by our main assembly and needs to be flexible. Having two base classes I think will do the trick.

@LasseV.Karlsen I converted your comments to an answer. Hope you don't mind, and thanks again.

Not at all! If I leave comments, and there is something useful there you can use to write an answer, more power to you!

As explained in the comments by @LasseV.Karlsen, the nullable open generic argument (in the base class) is the source of the problem.
This code is actually contained in a helper assembly used by our main systems, so it needs to be flexible. Some consuming assemblies use value types for the TUserKey primary key (e.g. int, long, Guid) and others use reference types (e.g. string).
So another approach is to split the hierarchy in two: one for value and one for reference types.
The base classes:
public abstract class Parent
{
  protected Parent() { }
  public long Id { get; }
  // other properties...
}


public abstract class ParentValue<TUserKey> : Parent
  where TUserKey : struct, IEquatable<TUserKey>      // <-----
{
  protected ParentValue() { }
  protected ParentValue(TUserKey? userId) { UserId = userId; }
  public TUserKey? UserId { get; }
}


public abstract class ParentReference<TUserKey> : Parent
  where TUserKey : class, IEquatable<TUserKey>       // <-----
{
  protected ParentReference() { }
  protected ParentReference(TUserKey? userId) { UserId = userId; }
  public TUserKey? UserId { get; }
}

The consumer would define a subclass. For value types:
public sealed class Child : ParentValue<long>
{
  private Child() : base() { }
  public Child(long? userId) : base(userId) { }
}

Or reference types:
public sealed class Child : ParentReference<string>
{
  private Child() : base() { }
  public Child(string? userId) : base(userId) { }
}

